# static_cast and passing void pointers c++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

```
void function(void * array, size_t itemsInArray, size_t sizeOfEachItem, int(*compare)(const void*, const void*))

char * array_ptr = static_cast<char*>(array);

char * ptr1 = items_ptr;
char * ptr2 = items_ptr + 1; 

void * array_ptr_void1 = static_cast<void*>(ptr1);
void * array_ptr_void2 = static_cast<void*>(ptr2);

compare(array_ptr_void1, array_ptr_void2);
```

So the code I have here is basically what I am trying to accomplish, but I am obviously not understanding the void pointers and passing them to the compare function. What I am basically wanting to do is take the void pointer to array cast it to a char pointer so I can increment through it. Then I want to pass a specific parts to the compare function. I just really need someone to explain to me the logic behind what I am trying to do because I don't seem to understand passing void pointers to the compare function. I can't change the function prototype. My question isn't about incrementing through the char pointer, I understand that part and I am just using item_ptr and item_ptr+1 to demonstrate passing a specific part of the array. The last line of code breaks when I send to parts to be compared, so I need to understand the flaw in my logic. Thanks!

Comment: Are you dealing with legacy C interfaces?

Comment: Then you probably don't need void pointers (nor raw arrays nor raw pointers). If you trying to implement something akin to a generic sort function, try to model it after `std::sort`.

Comment: I can't change the function prototype so I have to figure out how to deal with the data as I am receiving it.

Comment: So you are dealing with legacy interfaces. The answer by bala sreekanth is correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from your question. There are multiple versions of compare functions with different function names but with void pointers as arguments.
These functions are to handle different kinds of data.

And your function is to use these compare functions to compare arrays.
I think your function is not complete.

if items_ptr is type of char*  you should be using

```
   char * ptr1 = items_ptr;
   char * ptr2 = items_ptr + sizeOfEachItem;
```

If I am not wrong, you are looping/traversing through the buffer(array) pointed by array_ptr using items_ptr.

If so don't use + 1 to go to next item, instead using + sizeOfEachItem.
If you want to get nth element use  array_ptr + n*sizeOfEachItem

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes your definitely right. I understand what I have now isn't actually indexing based on the data size. I was just using that to try and figure out my logic for casting the void pointer, changing it, and then sending it to the compare function.

Comment: There is also a lot more to this function, I just need help understanding the  void pointer part and passing it to the compare function.

Comment: Void pointers are normally used in c style coding. With C++ features,  void pointers are rarely used. void pointers are c  way of doing a bit of function overloading, a bit of templates and a bit of is-a relation ship.